# Returning differences in array using count

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, count, max

Im currently having issue's with an algorithm im creating in php using 2 separate 2 dimensional arrays.

I want to Find how different 1 array is from the other and return the value.

For now my issue is that with the algorithm im using 'should' return the same value for the 2 arrays im comparing...but currently it does not.

The values in the arrays are as follows:

```
$array1 contains ['index','index','index','index','index']
$array2 contains ['index','java','index','none']
```

When i run my algorithm :

```
 function arrayDifference($array1,$array2)
 {
if (is_array($array1)&&is_array($array2)){
    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2); 
    $value=max(count($array1),count($array2));
    $result=$value-count($result);
    return $result;
}
}
```

I get these results:

```
When $array1 is passed in first the result is : 2.
When $array2 is passed in first the result is : 4.
```

The issue is that since im using the same arrays, should the resulting difference not be the same when both are passed in irrelevant of the parameter order?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Update/Note ---------------------------------------

After printing out array_diff the first values returned from $array1 being passed in first is :

```
'( [1] => java [3] => none )'
and for array2 passed in first:
'Array ( ) 1'
```

Comment: Start with outputting result of `array_diff($array1, $array2); `

Comment: ok i printed out the result of array_diff but it returned '1' instead of 2 or 4 which is somehow now even more confusing....

Comment: I don't understand what are you triyng to achieve, but it's obvious that order of arguments matters, as `array_diff` outputs values which exists only in __first__ passed array.

Comment: Yes this is what im thinking too but i dont understand why exactly...as im using the same array's twice...yet it only returns results for the first

Comment: Please understand the sentence from manual `returns the values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays`

Comment: ah right i misunderstood that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how array_diff() works.

In 1st case of $array1(first array in array_diff), there is only "index" value which is present in $array2 and therefore count(array_diff) is 0.

In 2nd case of $array2(first array in array_diff), there are 2 values (index,java)  which are not present in $array1 therefore count(array_diff) is 2.

Thats why in first case, you get 5-0 = 5
 Thats why in second case, you get 5-2 = 3

Comment: Fix `5 - 0 = 5` please